# How to create web-site with more than one user interface ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, user-interface

Currently I have complex web system created on ASP.NET MVC 2. The UI and server side are closely related. There are a lot of javascript script files and server inserts. Now I have to separate server side from UI, but I have to save site functionality. So, know there can be a various templates for site, but one server side. So, I am looking for best solution to resolve this task. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to have different type of themes for the same web application ??

Comment: If you extract all your business-logic and data-access into a separate project, you could just include this project in any site you want.

Comment: yes, and am looking for best practices how to create it

Comment: do you mean different users log in to your website and then you give them different access?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at : [Implementing themes in MVC](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/03/ASPNET-MVC-Implement-Theme-Folders-using-a-Custom-ViewEngine.aspx) .

Hope it helps